# Is it possible to get only specific HID in the scan result of ble scan?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, bluetooth-gatt

I get a list of all nearby ble/Bluetooth devices with scan operation.Like, I may get 150-200 devices in the list.But, I am interested to connect only with mouse and keyboard.So,Is it possible to get specific type of devices in the scan operation so that I get only mice and keyboards.

Comment: Your question is missing some information. How are you searching for devices right now?

Answer (score 1):

Generally HID devices include HID Service in the Service UUIDs AD type field of the BLE advertisement. The allocated UUID for **Human Interface Device** is **0x1812** according to the Bluetooth SIG specification [16-bit UUID Numbers Document](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf). It should be possible to filter your device list according to this information to find the HID devices.